# Changed pagination URLS to use p= instead of paged=

Tags: url-rewriting, pagination, htaccess, rewrite-rules

I am trying to rewrite my pagination URLs to use `p` instead of `paged` so they go from...

```
example.com/myposts?paged=2
```

to

```
example.com/myposts?p=2
```

How is the best way to do this? Do I need to use the rewrite API or can I do it via htaccess?